# a bugging query

Tags: sql, mysql

i need to get a query where the elements are displayed in case the first letter is E (the word is electronics).. i have tried with the following :

```
mysql_query("select * from nested_category where name like '[A-F]%'");
```

Edit : its like i need to choose all the elements for which the first element lie between A & F ..  I need all the element such as Elements, Capacitors, Elephant, Accelerators and definitely not  Resistors.. I am using this query with PHP...

Comment: Coronatus's answer seemed good for your original question, but your edit seems inconsistent.  Are you JUST looking for "Electronics"?  Or do you want "Capacitors" and "Electronics" but not "Resistors"?  Also, what is this, PHP?

Comment: please let me know if there are any further clarifications regarding my question..

Comment: @Lord T - `mysql_query()` is a PHP method.

Comment: Regexp works good ... but can i have the query using 'like' and not regexp.... ????

Comment: @Coronatus: I know that, but I find that on SO it's always worth double-checking to make sure an asker isn't accidentally mixing languages.

Comment: -1 for question wording: "a bugging query" is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WTF has A-F got to do with E?

`SELECT * FROM nested_category WHERE name LIKE 'E%'`

**In response to your edit:**

Use the [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) function:

`SELECT * FROMnested_category WHERE name REGEXP '^[A-E]'`

And even still, you now say you want A-E, but your code says A-F? I'm really confused by your question...

Comment: for REGEXP '^[A-E]'.... does it refer to the elements that begin with the letters from A to E??? if no, then whts the difference between this way of query and REGEXP '[A-E]'....

Comment: [A-E] is reversed in MySQL to [R-Z]. It says that in the documentation page that I linked to and you didn't read.

Comment: Sachindra, the "^" character in REGEXP means "start of line" (not negation). If you omit it, the regular expression will match something that merely contains the letter in the bracket group.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to continue using the mySql LIKE syntax is this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM nested_category
WHERE
(name LIKE 'A%'
OR name LIKE 'B%'
OR name LIKE 'C%'
OR name LIKE 'D%'
OR name LIKE 'E%')");
```